# Using Wordpress multisite is there a way to force HTTPS on specific subsites and not others?

Tags: multisite, ssl

I'm aware of the global variables that allow you to `FORCE_SSL` and `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN`. I am wanting to apply these settings on a per-site basis. For example, forcing SSL browsing and admin for a specific site on the network.

How can this be done?

Comment: Rob, as the [help] already states, your question is off topic (as any plugin recommendation): From the close reasons... _"Asking to recommend a product (plugin, theme, book, hosting provider), tool, library or off-site resource is out of scope of the site, as it attracts opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you can't log into your multi-site and go to the "General Settings" page (Settings > General). Update both the "WordPress address" and "Site address" URLs to use the "https://" protocol rather than "http://", as you can normally.